# MySQL - accessing a table sum and compare to another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, comparison

This is for a homework assignment. I just plain don't understand how to do it.

The instructions for this particular question is:

```
List the branch name for all branches that have at least one
book that has at least 4 copies on hand.
```

Where the tables in question are:

Branch:

```
BranchName        | BranchId
Henry Downtown    |    1
16 Riverview      |    2
Henry On The Hill |    3
```

Inventory:

```
BookId   |  BranchId  |  OnHand
   1     |     1      |     2
   2     |     3      |     4
   3     |     1      |     8
   4     |     3      |     1
   5     |     1      |     2
   6     |     2      |     3
```

From what I understand, I can get the number of OnHand per branch name with:

```
SELECT BranchName, SUM(OnHand) 
FROM Branch B, Inventory I 
WHERE B.BranchId = I.BranchId 
GROUP BY BranchName;
```

but I don't get how I'd do the comparison between the sum of OnHand per branch and 4.

Any help would be appreciated, guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this (assuming that the same book could be in different branches):

```
SELECT DISTINCT BranchName 
FROM Branch B, Inventory I 
WHERE B.BranchId = I.BranchId 
GROUP BY BranchName, I.BookId
HAVING SUM(onHand) >= 4;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a160f/2)

Is that what you had in mind?

**EDIT**

If Inventory table lists each book **only once for each branch**, then we can get rid of grouping by `bookid` and `DISTINCT` clause.

The query becomes:

```
SELECT BranchName 
FROM Branch B, Inventory I 
WHERE B.BranchId = I.BranchId 
GROUP BY BranchName
HAVING SUM(onHand) >= 4;
```

[This **SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a160f/3) is for the simplified query.

Comment: Yessir! Would you care to give me a step-by-step process of what is happening, if it's not much to ask? I'm new to SQL and it's just boggling my mind right now.

Comment: OK. We `GROUP` all records first by `branchname` and then by `bookid`. From the result we select only rows for which `HAVING` condition is true.  Since a single branch can have more than one book with at least 4 copies we use `DISTINCT` to return each branch only once.  If your `Inventory` table lists each book **only once for each branch**, then we can get rid of grouping by `bookid` and `DISTINCT` clause.